# How do I get a reference to a class library project to work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, .net-4.8

Using the following 2 files:

C# Class library project Target Framework: .NET v 5.0

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class MyExternalClass { }
}
```

C# console project .NET Framework: 4.8

```
using System;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyExternalClass myObj = new MyExternalClass();
            Console.WriteLine(myObj.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when running the program
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Copied details:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
HResult=0x80070002
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source=
StackTrace:

I've added the reference for the library as normal, and I didn't use any additional packages from NuGet. This is as minimalist as I can get.
This persists for every .NET target framework except for .NET Standard 2.0

I've read some possible fixes involving manual edits of visual studio files but none have worked for me so far, granted that they're several years old and involve other editions and frameworks.

Comment: .NET 5 and .NET Framework are fundamentally not compatible (don't be fooled by the naming / numbering), except via .NET Standard which seeks to function as a cross-framework standard for class libraries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard . The library needs to target .NET Standard rather than .NET 5 if you want to re-use it in .NET Framework projects.

Comment: See also [this article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3394865/net-5-what-the-merger-of-net-framework-and-net-core-means.html) which gives you a summary of the history which led to this situation.

Comment: Note that in @ADyson's answer, he uses _.NET 5_ not _.NET Framework 5.0_.  The Framework stops at 4.8.  .NET 5 is _Core_ not _Framework_.  I'm so glad I don't work there anymore; explaining version numbers to customers was hard enough in the v3.x days (when it ran on the 2.0 CLR).

Comment: Alright, how do I create a Class library using just the 4.8 .NET Framework?

Comment: I tried using .NET standard 2.1 and it still doesn't work. 2.0 standard is the only one that works at the moment.

Comment: `I tried using .NET standard 2.1 and it still doesn't work. ` Yes because 2.1 doesn't support .net framework. The table in the link I gave (and the answer below) shows that.

Comment: `how do I create a Class library using just the 4.8 .NET Framework?` ...create a new project in visual studio, select class library and select .net framework. But unless you need framework-only features (and don't care if it works with .net 5 projects) you'd be better to target .net standard 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to reference a library from a .NET framework project the libary needs to target .NET Framework or .NET Standard.

.NET 5 and .NET Framework are different beasts.

A good spot to see this is [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) article:. You can see there that .NET and .NET Framework are separate rows in the table showing .NET versions.

[image]

### .NET Standard 2.0

The answer to why "this persists for every .NET target framework except for .NET Standard 2.0" can be found in the in the same article:

> To find the highest version of .NET Standard that you can target, do the following steps:
>
> - (...)
> - Repeat this process for each platform you want to target. If you have more than one target platform, you should pick the smaller version among them. For example, if you want to run on .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 5.0, the highest .NET Standard version you can use is .NET Standard 2.0.

## 4.8 and 5.0. It's confusing.

Yes it can be confusing

In [Introducing .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/) from May 2019 Richard Lander, program manager in .NET Team, writes:

> ### .NET 5 = .NET Core vNext
>
> .NET 5 is the next step forward with .NET Core. (...)
> The project aims to improve .NET in a few key ways:
>
> - Produce a single .NET runtime and framework that can be used everywhere and that has uniform runtime behaviors and developer experiences.
> - Expand the capabilities of .NET by taking the best of .NET Core, .NET Framework, Xamarin and Mono.
> - (...)

Later he writes:

> We’re skipping the version 4 because it would confuse users that are familiar with the .NET Framework, which has been using the 4.x series for a long time. Additionally, we wanted to clearly communicate that .NET 5 is the future for the .NET platform.

And finally:

> Check out [.NET Core is the Future of .NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/) to understand how .NET 5 relates to .NET Framework.

Answer (score -1):

The error is probably due to version mismatch or change after creating the projects.

Recreate both projects targeting 4.8 version, it should solve the issue.